# Please reopen my question about the precise definition of standard molar entropy

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked the following question, which after some time was closed on the basis that it should "focus on one problem only":

[What is the precise definition of standard molar entropy?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126803/detailed-definition-of-standard-molar-entropy)

The last close vote was cast in spite of the fact that I'd edited it to include a rather prominent explanation that I'm asking exactly one question ("what is the precise definition of standard molar entropy?"). The question contains various other sentences that end in question marks, but these are by way of motivation for the main question ("what is the precise definition of standard molar entropy?") and would be answered by giving an answer to that question. The question is not concerned with any other problems at all, other than the problem of finding out the precise definition of standard molar entropy.

Consequently, I'm pretty sure it was closed in error and would like to ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: I still say it's much too broad. For example, "what's definition" and "is 0 entropy at 0 K arbitrary" also how entropy is found experimentally and what else? It feels like you'd wanna half a book about entropy put into an answer.

Comment: @Mithoron the question is "what is the precise definition of standard molar entropy?". To make the question more precise, I included what I know of how it's defined, and then I pointed out the holes in my knowledge that I want to fill, which have to do with how the third law enters the calculation. I could leave those out (and in one edited version, did) but that would make the question *less* focused, not more, since I would just be asking for the definition and not explaining what I do and don't already know about it.

Comment: I think it's an extremely straightforward question. The standard molar entropy of water is 41 J/K/mol, but what does that imply, physically, about water? To answer that we need to know the definition of SME, and to answer that we need to know the answer to my questions about how third law calculations are performed and treated when determining the SME of water. But there is still only one question, and it's a completely well defined and actually quite basic one. It would seem to me rather absurd if something as simple as this could not be asked.

Answer (score 6):

I have reviewed the question and agree that it shouldn't be closed.

Actually I think your later edit  made the question weaker, so I included parts of it again. It should be now in the [reopen review queue](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/111350), but if there are no other objections, I'd speed the process along. But let's give it the weekend.

Comment: Thank you, your edits have improved the question a lot.